# the error distributionNotFound for pytest

Tags: python, pytest

I have installed pytest on my system. when i am running the command using  pytest. i'm getting the following error.

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pytest", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3095, in <module>
    @_call_aside
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3081, in _call_aside
    f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3108, in _initialize_master_working_set
    working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 658, in _build_master
    ws.require(__requires__)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 959, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 846, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'pathlib2>=2.2.0' distribution was not found and is required by pytest`

Also, I typed on CLI 'pip install pathlib2'

`Requirement already satisfied: pathlib2 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (2.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: scandir in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from pathlib2) (1.9.0)
Requirement already satisfied: six in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from pathlib2) (1.11.0)`

but It doesn't works, same error.

Comment: And I tried 'pip install pathlib2==2.2.0' too. 

but, if I type pytest on CLI, I meet with the above error, 'distributionNotFound: The 'pathlib2>=2.2.0' distribution was not found and is required by pytest '

Comment: This is not a `pytest` issue, but a more general one. You have installed the brewed python along the system one MacOS ships already. If you want to use the brewed python, you need to make sure its lib comes first in `sys.path`, e.g. `PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7 pytest` (or whatever the correct installation directory is on your machine). This is what Homebrew also informs you about when running `brew install python2`.